# Regex in Grakn query

Tags: python, regex, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I want to match two string

```
string1 : Excessive Error Rate (STS/HO VC and VT/LO VC)
```

```
string2 : Excessive Error Rate STS/HO VC and VT/LO VC
```

similarly there are other set of string3 and string4 where the difference is only parenthesis in between the string which we don't know in a sense where is the parenthesis used.

Let say I want to get string1 using a regular expression on string2 such that it could be a generic for all such cases.

The main aim is to use regex on string2 in a query so that that query would understand it as string1 and give the result

```
match
$a isa alarm,
has alarm_id $id,
has alarm_name $alrm_nm;
{$alrm_nm "Excessive Error Rate STS/HO VC and VT/LO VC";} or {$alrm_nm like "Excessive Error Rate STS/HO VC and VT/LO VC";};
get $id;offset 0; limit 30;
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to be able to match any string (call it `string1`), to some other string (`string2`) where the only difference is that string2 contains parenthesis somewhere in addition to the contents of `string1`. I do not think regex can solve this problem generically. If we want to get into the theory, regex's can only recognize regular languages, or alternatively parse strings as finite automata - generically comparing any two strings with a single regex doesn't fit this pattern.

For a single starting `string`, you may be able to build a very complex regex that searches for all possible combinations of starting parenthesis location (`(`) with a sequence of required characters followed by `)`, but this is a large search space that will not be very fast.

Perhaps we can find an alternative approach that fits the Grakn data model better as well: assuming you have control of the creation of the database, we can simplify the search with a better schema!

1. Define a new relation relating similar attributes. We can use a new schema as follows:

```
define 
parenthetical-alarm-name sub relation, 
  relates alarm-name-parenthesis, 
  relates alarm-name-simple;
alarm-name sub attribute, datatype string,
  plays alarm-name-parenthesis,
  plays alarm-name-simple;
```

2. Now, when inserting an `alarm-name` `$a1` with value "hello (world)", on the application level, check if there are any parentheses in the string. If so remove them and insert this name as a new `alarm-name` `$a2`, creating "hello world".
3. We then create a new `parenthetical-alarm-name` between `$a1` and `$a2`.

Doing this all in one step would look like this:

```
$a1 "hello (world)" isa alarm-name;
$a2 "hello world" isa alarm-name; 
$r (alarm-name-parenthesis: $a1, alarm-name-simple: $a2) isa parenthetical-alarm-name;
```

Now, at query time, we can do all kinds of fun stuff! If we know the simple, non-parenthetical name $a1

```
match $a1 "hello world"; ($a1, $a2) isa parenthetical-alarm-name; get;
```

for instance would get you all the variations of parenthesis stored in Grakn that lead to "hello world".

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is that it may or may not have parenthesis then your regex to match on both is 
`(Excessive Error Rate )\(?(STS\/HO VC and VT\/LO VC)\)?` then just return `$1$2`

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I am looking for something more generic, which could handle any string but the difference between two strings would be only the parenthesis!

Comment: If you can reverse your checking so that we're matching the string with the parenthesis against the one without, instead of the other way around (instead of " use regex on string2 in a query so that that query would understand it as string1 and give the result" it would be "use regex on string1 in a query so that that query would understand it as string2 and give the result") then regex could easily strip out the parenthesis for you.  It can't do the other way around though.  I don't know Grakn so I can't speak on the other solution posted above